# Lucene: prefix query not working with WhitespaceAnalyzer

Tags: java, api, lucene

I'm experimenting a little with Lucene's diverse Query objects and I'm trying to understand why a prefix query doesn't match any documents when using a WhitespaceAnaylzer for indexing. Consider the following test code:

```
protected String[] ids = { "1", "2" };
protected String[] unindexed = { "Netherlands", "Italy" };
protected String[] unstored = { "Amsterdam has lots of bridges",
        "Venice has lots of canals" };
protected String[] text = { "Amsterdam", "Venice" };

@Test
public void testWhitespaceAnalyzerPrefixQuery() throws IOException, ParseException {
    File indexes = new File(
            "C:/LuceneInActionTutorial/indexes");

    FSDirectory dir = FSDirectory.open(indexes);

    IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_4_9,
            new LimitTokenCountAnalyzer(new WhitespaceAnalyzer(
                    Version.LUCENE_4_9), Integer.MAX_VALUE));
    IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(dir, config);

    for (int i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
        Document doc = new Document();
        doc.add(new StringField("id", ids[i], Store.NO));
        doc.add(new StoredField("country", unindexed[i]));
        doc.add(new TextField("contents", unstored[i], Store.NO));
        doc.add(new Field("city", text[i], TextField.TYPE_STORED));
        writer.addDocument(doc);
    }
    writer.close();

    DirectoryReader dr = DirectoryReader.open(dir);
    IndexSearcher is = new IndexSearcher(dr);
    QueryParser queryParser = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_4_9,
            "contents", new WhitespaceAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_4_9));
    queryParser.setLowercaseExpandedTerms(true);
    Query q = queryParser.parse("Ven*");
    assertTrue(q.getClass().getSimpleName().contains("PrefixQuery"));
    TopDocs hits = is.search(q, 10);
    assertEquals(1, hits.totalHits);
}
```

If I replace the WhitespaceAnaylzer with the StandardAnalyzer the test passes though. I used Luke to inspect the index content, but couldn't find any differences in how Lucene stores the values during indexing. Could anybody please clarify what's going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`StandardAnalyzer` lowercases text when it is indexed.  `WhitespaceAnalyzer` does not.  The term in the index, with `WhitespaceAnalyzer` is "Venice".

The query parser will lowercase your query though, since you have set `setLowercaseExpandedTerms(true)` (this is also the default, to disable this you need to explicitly set it to false).  So your query is "ven*", which does not match "Venice".

Comment: Ok, now I got it. Setting the "setLowercaseExpandedTerms" value to false and replacing the prefix with "Ven*" works. Thank you very much!

Comment: It seems not right to me that the QueryParser lowercases the terms by default. Thanks for the tip @femtoRgon